# Взаимодействие с "большими" данными на Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-search-view

Есть `.txt` файл со списком городов и их параметрами (id, name, lon, lat, country и т.д.) весом в 3.5 мб.

Есть приложение на `android`с `SearchView` в котором требуется для поискового запроса среди вышеперечисленных данных только name.

Собственно вопрос - каким способом в приложении инициализировать такой список данных?

Первое что пришло в голову - написать небольшую утилиту которая конвертирует все это дело в json с именами городов и в адаптере для поиска, который генерирует нужные данные для `SearchView` работать с ними, и просто засунуть в корень проекта. Но я уверен способов множество - какой вы можете посоветовать для использования на платформе `android`, ведь там достаточно жесткие требования к оптимизации из-за железа данных устройств.

И соотвественно последующий вопрос. Список этих городов после обработки будет храниться списком унаследованного от `List`, какой вариант будет более подходящий с учетом того что в будущем этот список будет преобразован в `MatrixCursor`?

Comment: Сгенерировать индекс-файл - самое то, лучше только индекс, разбитый на отдельные файлы.

Comment: А почему на базе этого не сделать обычную базу данных (sqlite) и дальше по накатанным туториалам?

Comment: @KoVadim уже используется бд, но немного для других целей и немного другая. Этот список нужен сугубо только для работы searchview. Или вы предлагаете просто этот список хранить с помощью бд?

Comment: да, хранить этот список в базе. Это сильно упростит Вам жизнь.

Comment: БД самый разумный выбор в вашей ситуации

Comment: Да - наверное так и поступим. Подготовил документ только с именами городов. После чего сделаю так, что бы при первом запуске приложения генерировалась бд с одним параметром записи - имя. А уже непосредственно в запросе query просто будет формировать обыкновенный курсор, без дополнительных List'ов и прочего

Comment: Если вы уже используете БД, то нет надобности создавать еще одну БД - вам потребуется только дополнительная таблица в уже существующей БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету @KoVadim при первом запуске инициирую из заполняю бд (orm=realm) значениями из .txt файла. После чего в методе `query(...)` работаю напрямую с бд, получая `List` моих данных. Разве что появилась другая проблема - как я понял с `realm`'om нельзя работать без собственных велосипедов т.к. он не поддерживает архитектуру контент провайдеров и, вроде, не может возвращать самый обыкновенный курсор

Comment: Вам не нужен курсор при работе с Realm, данная БД имеет [свой адаптер](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#working-with-android) для биндинга данных в списки

Comment: @pavlofff вы правы, даже есть свой realmSearchView - https://realm.io/news/android-search-text-view/